# How can I copy almost all field values into a duplicated row in Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a program which splits the `Lines Of Business` field on commas, then takes those split values and distributes them over duplicate rows of the original row, in a column called `lob`.  The primary key is an auto-generated `ID`.

Here is a concise example of desired behavior (many fields omitted for visual clarity):

Before running module:

> ```
>  +--------------------------------------------+
>  |  ID   | App Code  |   Lines Of Business    |
>  +-------+-----------+------------------------+
>  |   1   |    AB23   | Value1, Value 2,Value3 |
>  +------ +-----------+------------------------+
>  |   2   |    XY45   |         Value 2        |
>  +--------------------------------------------+
> ```

After running module:

> ```
>  +-------------------------------------------------------+
>  |  ID   | App Code  |   Lines Of Business    |   lob    |
>  +-------+-----------+------------------------+----------+
>  |   1   |    AB23   | Value1, Value 2,Value3 |  Value1  |
>  +-------+-----------+------------------------+----------+
>  |   2   |    XY45   |         Value 2        |  Value 2 |
>  +-------+-----------+------------------------+----------+ 
>  |   3   |    AB23   | Value1, Value 2,Value3 |  Value 2 |
>  +-------+-----------+------------------------+----------+
>  |   4   |    AB23   | Value1, Value 2,Value3 |  Value3  |
>  +-------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

You will see several similar statements in the code below, including:

```
strSOC1 = ![SOC 1] & ""
strL3 = ![L3] & ""
strAppCode = ![App Code] & ""
```

and

```
![Current Lifecycle Phase] = strCurrentLifecyclePhase
![SOC 1] = strSOC1
![L3] = strL3
```

What I would like to do is simplify this so that instead of creating a variable for each field that needs to be copied over to the new duplicate row (i.e. the `App Code` field in the table above), all fields (except for `lob` which is generated by the split on commas) are copied over at once.

I have dozens of other fields which need to be copied over, so to complete this with my current method would result in me creating a long list of variables (or a dictionary) and the code would not be portable to other tables.

So, how could I accomplish this?

Here is my code, which has had much help from other SO users since I am quite new to VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReformatTable()

    Dim db                       As DAO.Database
    Dim rs                       As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsADD                    As DAO.Recordset

    Dim strSQL                   As String
    Dim strLinesOfBusiness       As String
    Dim strSOC1                  As String
    Dim strCurrentLifecyclePhase As String
    Dim strL3                    As String
    Dim strL4                    As String
    Dim strlob                   As String
    Dim strAppCode               As String
    Dim varData                  As Variant
    Dim i                        As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb

    ' Add a field into the existing IIPM table called lob.
    ' Values created during the Line Of Business split will be stored here.
    Dim strDdl As String
    strDdl = "ALTER TABLE IIPM ADD COLUMN lob TEXT(255);"
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl

    ' Select all fields that have a Line of Business and are unprocessed (lob is Null)
    strSQL = "SELECT *, lob FROM IIPM WHERE ([Lines Of Business] Is Not Null) AND ([lob] Is Null)"

    Set rsADD = db.OpenRecordset("IIPM", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

    With rs
        While Not .EOF
            strLinesOfBusiness = ![Lines Of Business] & "" ' Append empty string to mitigate error when cell in field is null
            strCurrentLifecyclePhase = ![Current Lifecycle Phase] & ""
            strSOC1 = ![SOC 1] & ""
            strL3 = ![L3] & ""
            strAppCode = ![App Code] & ""
            varData = Split(strLinesOfBusiness, ",") ' Get all comma delimited fields

            ' Update First Record
            .Edit
            !lob = Trim(varData(0)) ' remove spaces before writing new fields
            ![App Code] = strAppCode
            .Update

            ' Add records with same first field
            ' and new fields for remaining data at end of string
            For i = 1 To UBound(varData)
                With rsADD
                    .AddNew
                    ![Lines Of Business] = strLinesOfBusiness
                    ![Current Lifecycle Phase] = strCurrentLifecyclePhase
                    ![SOC 1] = strSOC1
                    ![L3] = strL3
                    ![L4] = strL4
                    !lob = Trim(varData(i)) ' remove spaces before writing new fields
                    ![App Code] = strAppCode
                    .Update
                End With
            Next
            .MoveNext
        Wend

        .Close
        rsADD.Close

    End With

    Set rsADD = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

    ' Remove empty rows which only contain an ID.
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "DELETE FROM IIPM WHERE lob IS NULL AND [App Code] IS NULL AND [Lines Of Business] IS NULL;"

    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: *"many other fields which need to be copied over"*  How many?  Dozens?

Comment: @HansUp:  Yes, dozens, though less than 60. I will update the OP with this.

Comment: That's what I feared.  Let's say 58 fields total.  That means for each duplicated record, you will repeat the information already stored for 56 fields --- all of them except `ID` and `lob`.  If you're determined to do that, I'm sure Andre's solution will do it.  But I encourage you to look into [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization): *"Database normalization, or simply normalization, is the process of organizing the columns (attributes) and tables (relations) of a relational database to minimize data redundancy."*

Comment: @HansUp: Thank you! I will give that a read now.  It looks like it could really help to optimize my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I find all these

```
strL3 = ![L3] & ""
```

and

```
![L3] = strL3
```

problematic - you are converting NULL values to empty strings, there is no reason to do that.

Second, to do this for all fields, you can loop the `Recordset.Fields` collection.

Get rid of all the `str<Fieldname>` variables, and do this:

```
Dim fld As DAO.Field

' ...

Set rsADD = db.OpenRecordset("IIPM", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

With rs
    While Not .EOF
        varData = Split(rs![Lines Of Business], ",") ' Get all comma delimited fields

        ' Update First Record
        .Edit
        !lob = Trim(varData(0)) ' remove spaces before writing new fields
        ' ![App Code] = strAppCode  ' unnecessary
        .Update

        ' Add records with same first field
        ' and new fields for remaining data at end of string

        For i = 1 To UBound(varData)
            rsADD.AddNew
            For Each fld In rsADD.Fields
                If fld.Name <> "lob" And fld.Name <> "ID" Then
                    ' Copy all fields except "lob" and "ID"
                    rsADD(fld.Name) = rs(fld.Name)
                End If
            Next fld
            ' lob is set separately, ID is set automatically
            rsADD!lob = Trim(varData(i))   ' remove spaces before writing new fields
            rsADD.Update
        Next i

        .MoveNext
    Wend

    .Close
    rsADD.Close

End With

Set rsADD = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

Note: nested `With` blocks are problematic, so I have always used the recordset names.

Comment: The reason that I did that was that if I did not convert it to a string, then I get an error whenever a cell in that field has a null value.  I agree with you though, it is certainly not an optimal solution.

Comment: I see, this could be avoided by using variables of type `Variant` instead of `String`. But it is even easier to directly set `rsTarget.myField = rsSource.myField`, without a variable inbetween.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I'll try it out!

Comment: I still need to update the first record before the for loop, right?

Comment: I am finding that when I update the record before the for loop, or even if I don't update the record at all, the program runs until it stops responding.  This happens even if I use my previous method to update the first record before the for loop.

Comment: @Paradox: I have added more of your original code to give context. Maybe you had deleted the `.MoveNext` of `rs` by accident.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue.  Thank you.